# How can I ensure AngularJS is run on my HTML and that a module is loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I asked a question earlier about [How to populate a select dropdow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs)

When I tried to implement this:

```
<html lang="en" class="light" data-ng-app="test">
<body data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            angular.module('test', []).controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.selectedTestAccount = null;
                $scope.testAccounts = [];

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/Admin/GetTestAccounts',
                    data: { applicationId: 3 }
                }).success(function (result) {
                    $scope.testAccounts = result;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But it's giving me an error in the Chrome Developer tools saying:

```
Uncaught Error: No module: test
```

I notice that the person who answered my post mentioned I would need to ensure Angular is run on my HTML and the module is loaded. Well I did include Angular in the script area but I still get the above message. Can anyone advise me what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: why are you wrapping angular code in `document.ready`?

Comment: @charlieftl - Good point !   Thanks for pointing this out to me. I guess I am just so used to using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put `ngApp` above the `module` declaration, obviously, angular tries to initiate the `module` *before* it is declared.

You have two options:

1. Put the module declaration to `head`, therefore it would be ready when `ngApp` directive tries to initialize.
2. Initialize your application manually using `angular.bootstrap`.

### Initializing Manually:

```
angular.bootstrap(angular.element("body")[0], ["test"]);
```

Docs:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap

Comment: I completely removed it from the html and added your suggested line:

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(angular.element("body")[0], ["test"]);
            angular.module('test', []).controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {   but it still is saying that it cannot find any module test. Is there something obvious I am missing. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are *still* trying to bootstrap before declaration. `bootstrap` must be called after module declaration. Put it at the end.

Comment: thanks very much. Now that you pointed it out I feel a bit stupid to have made such a basic mistake. It's working okay now.

Answer (score 2):

Use a directive. Don't use jQuery in that way. This was my first (and main) error when started with angular from a strong jQuery background.

If you need to manipulate a dom element, in most cases, the right way is a directive

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive