# Data not binding properly in angular in list box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I am using the below to code to get data in a list box.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-6">Year Built</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select ng-model="property.yearBuilt"
                            id="yearBuilt"
                            rb-default-year="currentYear"
                            ng-options="year.yearFourDigit as year.yearFourDigit for year in years">
                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But somoehow the data is not binding properly with html. I am getting blank list box 50% of the times.

Can anyone please help me in this?

I wanted to post a picture showing what I am seeing, but I don't have a 10 in reputation to be able to do that.

Comment: hope this link will help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs

Comment: try this too  http://plnkr.co/edit/lrn0NNMNbIVE4rS4Fytd?p=info

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: I will create a fiddle and see if I am able to replicate this error. I will share the fiddle link here once I create.

Comment: @Aru 

when i inspect the element now, I get something like this.

<option value="? number:2010 ?"></option> and this is not showing up in the list box.

Comment: try to post a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gscpjv8r/ can you see why this is not working. in some cases when I commit, it gives me something like this -->


`<select ng-model="property.yearBuilt" ng-options="year.yearFourDigit as year.yearFourDigit for year in years" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched"><option value="" class="">--Select--</option><option value="12">2008</option><option value="13">2007</option><option value="14">2006</option><option value="15" selected="selected">2005</option>`

but in the list box I don't see any value, i should see 2005.