# Drop/down select or normal select with JSON data in ui grid?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-select2

Hi have tree grid with Json data i want to integrate select feature for that I found this-> "http://plnkr.co/edit/Rk8y2N7p30VHNancDWnk?p=preview"

But i am unable to integrate with JSON data. Please help me.

I want this [http://plnkr.co/edit/rZmdUWE9XYOrOuEcjKjt?p=preview] to be working, can u plz check and make it workable.

And i am trying for drop down selection, need help for this as well.

but i am not getting any open source API for select and multiselect drop/down in UI grid with Json. plz help

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myFilters', []).filter('nameFilter', function(){
  return function(people, selected) {
    var filtered = [];
    if(selected.length > 0){
      for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        var person = people[i];
        for(var z = 0; z < selected.length; z++ ) {
          if(selected[z].name == person.name) {
            filtered.push(people[i]);
          } 
        }
      }
    } else {
      filtered = people;
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});

var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'ui.grid', 'myFilters']);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  
  $scope.person = {};

  $scope.people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 10 },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30 },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 31 },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefanía@email.com', age: 16 },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54 },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43 },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21 }
  ];
  
  $scope.personName = {};
  $scope.personName.selected = [];
  
  $scope.personEmail = {};
  $scope.personEmail.selected = [];
  
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: $filter('nameFilter')($scope.people, $scope.personName.selected),
   enableFiltering: true
  };

  $scope.refreshData = function() {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $filter('nameFilter')($scope.people, $scope.personName.selected);
  };


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS ui-select</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">


  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css" />

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.9.0/select.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.9.0/select.css">

  <script src="demo.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <hr>
<div>
   <ui-select multiple ng-model="personName.selected" ng-change="refreshData()" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | filter: $select.search">
                 <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
        </div>     
<div>
   <ui-select multiple ng-model="personEmail.selected" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$item.email}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | filter: $select.search">
                                 <small ng-bind-html="person.email | highlight: $select.search"></small> 
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
        </div>            
  
  <hr>
<div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks :)

Comment: Use the ng-options directive of angular js. refer this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs

Comment: thank you prasad, but i am finding difficulties in integrating my tree grid with select :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a directive, Refer the discussion here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable about custom editors.

Comment: nope my query is to add select to ui grid. in the above program it has done properly. But i want the same with JSON data.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rZmdUWE9XYOrOuEcjKjt?p=preview

check this and make it workable. this is exactly what i want.


here it is not filtering the data