# How to display data in select box using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi I want to bind the zipcode's in the select box from the following data. 
How to do that ??

```
[[{'zipcode':'6451105'},{'zipcode':'641515'},{'zipcode':'564555'}]]
```

Comment: I think the best way is using `ng-options` [check the following link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs)

Comment: You realise your data has multiple `zipcode` keys in the same object? Should it perhaps be `[{'zipcode':'6451105'},{'zipcode':'641515'},{'zipcode':'564555'}]`

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to bind one of your zipcode objects to a property, eg

```
{zipcode: '641515'}
```

and your **actual data** looks like this

```
[{'zipcode':'6451105'},{'zipcode':'641515'},{'zipcode':'564555'}]
```

this should suffice

```
<select name="zipCode" ng-model="zipCode"
    ng-options="zipCode.zipcode for zipCode in zipCodes"></select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rY0cFVqyZHVoB4DyZj1Z?p=preview

Comment: Hi Phill, Thank you for your reply ... i Want to display all the zipcodes in dropdown one by one .Still i din't get the solution.

Comment: @Gopinath I don't understand what you mean by *"one by one"*

Comment: Hi Phil I got the solution thank you very much.