# Populate dropdown value inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing an issue with my Angular code, while populating the dropdown inside a HTML table (Code given below).
Could you please help me with what should be done inside modify() to populate the dropdown ?

**HTML Code:**

```
<table class="table" ng-app="empApp" ng-controller="employeeController">
<thead>
    <tr class="info">
        <th>Emp Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
  <td>
    <div ng-hide="editingData[emp.id]">{{ emp.name }}</div>
    <div ng-show="editingData[emp.id]"><input type="text" ng-model="emp.name" /></div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div ng-hide="editingData[emp.id]">{{ emp.status.name }}</div>
    <select ng-show="editingData[emp.id]" class="form-control" ng-model="emp.status" 
    ng-options="status.id  as status.name for status in statuses"></select>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="editingData[employee.id]" ng-click="modify(emp)">Modify</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="editingData[employee.id]" ng-click="update(emp)">Update</button>&nbsp;
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
    var empApp = angular.module("empApp", []);
    empApp.controller('employeeController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.statuses = [{"id":1,"name":"Active"}, {"id":1,"name":"Inactive"}];

    $scope.employees = [{"id":1,"name":"Mark","status":{"id":1,"name":"Active"}},{"id":2,"name":"Sara","status":{"id":2,"name":"Inactive"}}]; 
    $scope.editingData = {};

    for (var i = 0, length = $scope.employees.length; i < length; i++) {
        $scope.editingData[$scope.employees[i].id] = false;
    }

    $scope.modify = function(employee){
        $scope.editingData[employee.id] = true;
        //Set Employee Status correctly here to populate the dropdown

    };
  });
```

My problem is I am NOT able to populate the dropdown with the existing value, as show in the diagram below:
[image]

Comment: In your buttons it's `editingData[employee.id]`, it should be `editingData[emp.id]` isn't it?

Comment: And what's the problem you're facing in your dropdown?

Comment: Should this `ng-hide="editingData[employee.id]"` not be `ng-hide="editingData[emp.id]"`

Comment: You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/s5t8yus2/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZS474VApoqhbbg7FKC8L), check if it's what you need.

**1: Both status are with id 1. Change them**

From:

```
$scope.statuses = [{"id":1,"name":"Active"}, {"id":1,"name":"Inactive"}];
```

To:

```
$scope.statuses = [{"id":1,"name":"Active"}, {"id":2,"name":"Inactive"}];
```

**2:Change your select ng-model to emp.status.id.**

From:

```
<select ng-show="editingData[emp.id]" class="form-control" ng-model="emp.status" 
    ng-options="status.id  as status.name for status in statuses"></select>
```

To:

```
<select ng-show="editingData[emp.id]" class="form-control" ng-model="emp.status.id" 
    ng-options="status.id  as status.name for status in statuses"></select>
```

**3: Change your buttons ng-hide/ng-show**

From:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="editingData[employee.id]" ng-click="modify(emp)">Modify</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="editingData[employee.id]" ng-click="update(emp)">Update</button>&nbsp;
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="editingData[emp.id]" ng-click="modify(emp)">Modify</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="editingData[emp.id]" ng-click="update(emp)">Update</button>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Update:
As @Rajesh said below you can store the status_id instead of entire status object. 
 Check [his fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5t8yus2/2/).

Comment: Just 1 pointer. Its would be better to store status_id instead of entire status object. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/s5t8yus2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your select tag part with this code

```
<select ng-show="editingData[emp.id]" class="form-control" ng-model="emp.status" 
    ng-options="status as status.name for status in statuses track by status.id"></select>
```

This is because in ng-model you are passing the full object and you need the full object to be tracked by ID in order to fill the dropdown and relevant dropdown value to be selected

Also in your buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="editingData[emp.id]" ng-click="modify(emp)">Modify</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="editingData[emp.id]" ng-click="update(emp)">Update</button>&nbsp;
    </div>
```

Because you are referencing it by 'emp' and not 'employee' inside ng-repeat as it will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
```

But in the select list, you are toggling based on:

```
editingData[employee.id]
```

Try changing that to

```
editingData[emp.id]
```

Comment: No going to work - heres way - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

use emp.id in your button and also in your modify function and loop
use $scope.employees[i].isVisible = false and ng-hide = $scope.employees.isVisible ng-show = $scope.employees.isVisible