# How to create Dynamic Query using AJAX

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to create a `dynamic query` `(Select * from <table name> where ..)` using `angular js, html, javascript`. The drop-down should come for the conditions `('and' , 'or', etc)` `e.g. -> select <dropdown> from <dropdown> where <dropdown>` . 
I am new to it. So please explain in proper example.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: A simple example would be make an ajax call to your controller to get data from the database and then bind the data to your drop down.

Comment: Can u please show an example?

Comment: Here see an example from  question already asked in SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs

Comment: I think you should at least try to start to implement something before you ask for help on SO, and if you have, please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'DropDownController',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function() {
            $("#drpDown").append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: this,
                    html: this
                })
            );
        });
    }
});
```

What happens at the endpoint is some controller`DropDownController` may be if you are using `Spring MVC` it would be something like `/DropDownController` where you can write you `query to call database` using `orm` or whatever you use and returned is `json` which `binds to the dropdown with id="drpDown"`