# Trying to populate a dropdown list from a REST call using angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I was using this thread as a reference [How can I populate a select dropdown list from a JSON feed with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688313/how-can-i-populate-a-select-dropdown-list-from-a-json-feed-with-angularjs)

My code does not throw any errors, but the dropdown list does not contain any of the values expected. The data is successfully grabbed from the api call and stored into the variable $scope.dataTypes.

At execution time,

```
$scope.dataTypes = ['string', 'integer', 'double']
```

But again, the dropdown list is empty. The other two variables, TemplateName and ColumnCount are displaying correctly.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        function GetDataTypes($scope, $http) {
            $scope.dataTypes = [];
            $scope.TemplateName = 'NameTest';
            $scope.ColumnCount = '20';
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:60568/GetDataTypes'
            }).then(function (result) {
                $scope.dataTypes = result.data.Result;
                console.log(dataTypes);
            });
        }
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
        myApp.controller("GetDataTypes", GetDataTypes);
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="TemplateScreen" ng-controller="GetDataTypes">
        TemplateName :- <input ng-model="TemplateName" type="text" id="TemplateName" value="" /><br />
        ColumnCount :- <input ng-model="ColumnCount" type="text" id="ColumnCount" value="" /><br />
        Select DataType :-
            <select ng-model="dataTypes">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        <div id="divTemplateName">{{TemplateName}}</div>
        <div id="divColumnCount">{{ColumnCount}}</div><br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Console Output of $scope.dataTypes at execution time

```
(5) ["INTEGER_DATATYPE", "STRING_DATATYPE", "DOUBLE_DATATYPE", "BOOL_DATATYPE", "CHAR_DATATYPE"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat` to specify the contents of the dropdown list:

```
<select ng-model="selectedDataType">
    <option ng-repeat="dt in dataTypes">{{ dt }}</option>
</select>
```

Or you can use `ng-options` with the **label** for **value** in **array** syntax:

```
<select ng-model="selectedDataType"
        ng-options="dt for dt in dataTypes" />
```

In either case, you only use `ngModel` to bind to the selected item in the list.

Comment: Simply dropping this in did not work I get the same results - empty dropdown list. Is there additional code I need?

Comment: Seems strange, looks okay, is it not the same as [this example on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select_repeat)? Does `$scope.dataTypes` definitely get set correctly?

Comment: I've printed out $scope.dataTypes to console, included in OP.

Comment: I'm stumped! - Do either of the above dropdown examples work if you hardcode some string values into the `$scope.dataTypes` array (i.e. bypass the ajax call)?

Comment: Figured it out! Typo on the line <option ng-repeat="dt in dateTypes">{{ dt }}</option>. Should be dataTypes not dateTypes :P

Comment: Ha! No worries, I had a good laugh once I noticed it! Appreciate the help!